# Translating Android Keyboard Keys to multiple languages

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My idea is to make a software keyboard for Android with some new features I haven't seen yet. But, in order to reach the most users, I must provide support for multiple languages.

I'm looking at the Google SDK sample of a software keyboard, specifically the file named "`querty.xml`". I need that file, with the multiple languages characters (multiple XMLs files) with its typical distribution.

The problem is, I don't know where to obtain those "characters" and its distribution. Are there any resources,for example Android SO sources, to obtain these?

Note that I don't need dictionaries, because I won't provide text prediction. I only need the character pack and distribution; Keyboard-layout would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed it decoding some other keyboards APKs, and surprisingly they all look similar, so probably its what people do.